# warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[eclipselink.canonicalmodel.use_static_factory]'

Tags: jpa, entity

I get this warning message after every project I run, does anyone know what the reason is, and how to resolve it?

Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Chat\build\classes
warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[eclipselink.canonicalmodel.use_static_factory]'
1 warning
compile-single:
run-single:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

This occurs if the background compiler annotates the project with some compiler errors.

**Note:** the project contains compiler errors, not necessarily the file containing the `eclipselink` warning annotation.

To fix it :

**1. delete all the local history of the source file. Here is how :**

A. Pass from "Source View" to "History View" (via menu, View:Editors:History);

B. Select from the combo box "Filter" the value "Local";

C. Select all items in the below table;

D. Click the right mouse button;

E. Finally select "Delete from History"

**2. close the source file;**

**3. reopen the source file.**